# Add some characters to the end of URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I use a WordPress theme that has a number of custom post types. When I search for these post types, in the results page, the display order is from the oldest post to the newest post, but I want the newer posts to be displayed first.

I didn't design this template, so I don't know how to code it.

I found that by putting `orderby=new`  at the end of the URL of the site, the display order is fixed.

Is there a way to automatically add this phrase to the end of the URL when someone enters the results page?

The links are like this: `mydomain.com/activites/?location_name=paris&location_id=&taxonomy%5Bst_tour_type%5D=` to the phrase `mydomain.com/activites/?` It is constant in all searches and after that, it changes based on the term that the user searches for.

The word location is the post type and the rest of the parts that come in the url are taxonomy.

Comment: What does the anchor link look like? Meaning that how is it structured? Please provide this piece of code.

Comment: The links are like this:
` mydomain.com/activites/?location_name=paris&location_id=&taxonomy%5Bst_tour_type%5D= `

to the phrase ` mydomain.com/activites/? ` It is constant in all searches and after that, it changes based on the term that the user searches for.

Comment: And how is the link generated? Is there some logic behind it?

Comment: update your question, don't post it in comments

Answer (score 0):

**immediate answer:**
Write the link to the page accordingly. All other solutions will require changing some of the code or settings.
From my understanding of your question the cleanest solution is probably just to include a link back to the page itself with an added &orderby=new

Label the link in a way that makes it obvious to the user what it does. In this case I would assume ordering some type of content by release or entry date.

**recommended solution:**
Change the script in way that makes that order the default. It seems to be what you ideally "want". But can't do. As implied by the question.

**janky solution:**
Add a redirect. It's the same thing I said before but automatic without user input. The only benefit to this is being able to avoid touching existing code. And apply to all users as default.

**roundabout solution, that will make maintenance a nightmare long term:**
Rewrite rules in your web server. If you don't have access to that: try .htaccess
But since this modifies the behavior in a not immediately obvious way if is missing. And this will be easily missed by merit of being a hidden file and this type of config override not always being allowed. This might lead to non intuitive problems in the future.